# "fatal: Not a valid object name develop" error when running brew upgrade/cleanup

Tags: macos, homebrew, catalina

Whenever I run `brew upgrade` or `brew cleanup` I get this error in the output:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name develop
```

Although, it seems that upgrading works as expected. Where does the error come from and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the error has been caused by a misbehaving tap. After I've cleaned up taps with

```
brew untap <tapname>
```

the error disappeared.

P.S. to list all installed taps, just run:

```
brew tap
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message comes from git - a version-control system commonly used for source code.

The error message means that you have asked git to do "something" on a name "develop" that doesn't exist yet. Typically because the branch has not been created yet, or you're targetting a repository that has been reset/cleaned or similar and the branch doesn't exist there.